# How to get Microprocessor metadata?

Tags: arm, embedded

May not be appropriate for SO but I'll give it a shot:

Is there a place where I can get the **metadata** that describes the microprocessor or SoC for common chips and/or architectures at a block level? (mostly I'm interested in ARM products). CPU header files contain the majority of info that I want, but I'm looking for a more raw format (JSON, XML, etc) that is hopefully easier to parse than a C header file that includes extraneous things like structs and helper macros. Ideally this would also contain a short description of each block/register/bitfield. Do microprocessor companies release data of this form?

Here's a rough example of what I'm looking for if it were JSON formatted

```
cortexm3.json
-------------

{'mnemonic': "cm3", 
'name': "Cortex-M3"
'descr': "ARM's Cortex-M3 Microprocessor"
'blocks': [
    {'mnemonic':"NVIC",'baseaddr':"0xe000e000"}
     ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: Licensing the Cortex-M architecture IP is certainly possible albeit very expensive. There is a raw netlist available for academic use but that won't do you much good without an awful lot of painstaking reverse-engineering. There are freely available processor core implementations however, such as the Xilinx PicoBlaze or the OpenSPARC project. These are written in hardware description languages such as Verilog or VHDL.

Comment: Ah, this is more than what I'm looking for. I don't need to know how the logic is implemented, I just want what's already available in the public docs but in a much more compacted, raw form that only contains the memory mapping and minimal descriptions.

Comment: @toes: I see. Then C header are the closest to a universal description language you'll get for these. There's nothing like a JTAG BSDL format for I/O descriptors, though there are often proprietary descriptors from which the headers and/or chip descriptors for debuggers are generated and which you may also try parsing. Personally if I was forced to do this for a large set of architectures I'd go the route of parsing the header files, with ad-hoc rules describing how each compiler/MCU structures them.

Comment: arm is not a semiconductor company for starters.   and there is very little mapped from an address perspective in a cortex-m maybe a timer.  there are coprocessor registers, standard-ish mix, some will tell you about the processor, what instructions are available, etc.  as far as I/O, peripherals, etc you just read the datasheet from the silicon vendor, and yes they always have documentation, sometimes behind an nda, but cortex-m based ones generally publicly available,  which chips for example would you like to start with?

Comment: start with one/some specific parts with your question then move toward the generic.

Comment: note, arm (cortex-m) provides lots of information on all of its cores and their interfaces

Comment: @dwelch I use the term 'peripherals' loosely to also include logic blocks (e.g., NVIC on an ARM). Just getting a core description that includes information on all the logic bocks, registers, and bit fields even at an architectural descriptor level (i.e. not an actual silicon implementation) would be extremely helpful. If I could just get this information for, say, the cortex-m that would be a wonderful start. Then I would probably want to get for info on other ARM architectures (Cortex-R) before moving on to non ARM products.

Comment: @doynax At the place I work we also have a proprietary form of keeping our hardware descriptorsm and I also have not heard of any universal standard other than header files. I think though that even if the companies had a well defined proprietary format that would be better than trying to parse C headers full of macros. Perhaps there are other projects who have already done this leg work...

Comment: @dwelch I guess the way my question is stated does not make sense to you. I know that companies like ARM release public documentation for their products OBVIOUSLY. What I'm looking for is something *like* the header files they release, but excluding all the preprocessor directive cruft. You could describe what I'm looking for as a config file for a cpu. I will rework my question to make this more clear. If you were the one to downvote my question, in the future, try to understand the question before downvoting.

Comment: ahh, yeah I know what you are talking about it comes with the source, but other than the trm describing all the signals around the core I dont know of that publicly.  much of if not all of the configurable items (plus many others core specific that are not configurable) are in the coprocessor csrs, the cpuid stuff.  by definition you can imagine the header files contain the license that prevents distribution beyond the nda agreement.

Comment: You could run  a script on Linux device trees to convert from DT to JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ARM Cortex-M at least there are CMSIS-SVD [*System View Description (SVD)*](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/Pack/html/_create_pack__d_f_p.html#CP_SVD) files.  These are used by IDEs with microcontroller aware debugging features such as Keil's MDK-ARM.

IDEs for other architectures may have similar matadata information, however such data is likley to be in proprietary formats or schemas intended to support specific debuggers and architectures - there is no general standard "*electronic data sheet*" format for microcontrollers.

The [CMSIS-SVD](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-m/cortex-microcontroller-software-interface-standard.php?tab=CMSIS-SVD) format is well defined by ARM, but I believe applies only to ARM Cortex-M.  The format is also supported by Rowley Associates I believe, and there is an [Eclipse plug-in](http://mcuoneclipse.com/2014/05/29/how-to-add-register-details-view-in-eclipse/) that also uses them.

The SVD file for a specific Cortex-M part should be available from the part vendor, though they may not make it easy to find unless you are a tool vendor.  You can also download them from the [CMSIS-SVD Public Download Area](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/SVD/html/svd_web_public_pg.html), and of course you will find them in the tool-chain installation of any tool that supports them.

Comment: thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Too bad it's only for cortex-m but this gives me a good place to start.